# Installation of VSTO by adding registry in end user computers

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I've developed a VSTO addin for excel with VS2019. In my company execution of exe files are controlled by privilege management software (https://www.beyondtrust.com). For this reason, I don’t want to crate window installation file or setup.exe file. For this reason, I am traying to install VSTO by adding registry. My steps are as follow,

1. I have run VSTO addin from VS2019.
2. I have copy all registry from

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO\SolutionMetadata
3. Deleted all above-mentioned registry.
4. Moved all files (dll, manifest, VSTO etc) generated by VS2019 in new folder.
5. Re added all registry with old GUID and RSA key but only modification of path for new path of VSTO files.
   After that whenever I launch excel, my addin do not load and load behaver changed from 3 to 2. No matter even I change to 3, it got changed as 2. It always shown me my addin in inactive addin my option of excel.
   Can anyone guide me?
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create COM-AddIn using IExtensibility instead of VSTO addin.
It is similar to VSTO. Only change is u need to do everything by yourself including
user/machine registry